# How to know if user signed in with Google?

Tags: flutter, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, google-signin

On the client side, in Flutter

1. User signed in with Google using Fireabase Auth with email example@gmail.com
2. User logs out
3. User calls `fetchSignInMethodsForEmail` with example@gmail.com and it returns an empty list
4. Tries to create a new account, now with email and password with example@gmail.com
5. Failed with error `Signup failed [firebase_auth/email-already-in-use] The email address is already in use by another account.`

In step 3, why is it returning an empty list? I would expect `['google']` ?

My goal is to tell the user `Hey, use Google Authentication with this email` in case they forget.
Is this possible ?

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/11508

Answer (score -1):

Update:
It is now supported in GUI firebase console:

Uncheck this box

[image]

Disclaimer: You are disabling enumeration protection.

As of 15 September 2023, it is a security new feature enabled by default for new Firebase projects. It is called email enumeration protection.

You can Disable email enumeration protection using gcloud auth print-access-token use NodeJS firebase-admin or the command:

```
gcloud auth print-access-token --project=PROJECT_ID
```

Disable email enumeration protection using the Identity Toolkit API:

```
curl -X PATCH -d "{'email_privacy_config':{'enable_improved_email_privacy':"false"}}" \
    -H 'Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN' \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'X-Goog-User-Project: PROJECT_ID' \
"https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/admin/v2/projects/PROJECT_ID/config?updateMask=email_privacy_config"
```

Replace the following:

```
ACCESS_TOKEN: the access token you generated earlier
PROJECT_ID: your project ID
```

For firebase-admin, use:

```
import {getAuth} from "firebase-admin/auth";


import firebase from "firebase-admin";

import serviceAccount from "./path-to-firebase-adminsdk.json" assert { type: "json" };

firebase.initializeApp({
    credential: firebase.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
});


const ans = await  getAuth().projectConfigManager().updateProjectConfig(
    {
        emailPrivacyConfig: {
            enableImprovedEmailPrivacy: false,
        },
    }
);
console.log(ans)
```

There is a 2 month old github issue with more context https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/11810 , nothing to do with client. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/11810#issuecomment-1726320394

https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/admin/email-enumeration-protection